# wxWidget error : operator new : none of the 4 overload could convert all the argument type

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm on first time building a project using wxWidget in Visual Studio, all config for project follow as this : https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide

But now I have a problem when try to build this, in file any.h (from wxWidgets 3.1 include ), this error was appeared:

> Error 1   error C2665: 'operator new' : none of the 4 overloads could
>   convert all the argument types

At block:

```
class wxAnyValueTypeOpsInplace
{
public:
    static void DeleteValue(wxAnyValueBuffer& buf)
    {
        GetValue(buf).~T();
    }

    static void SetValue(const T& value,
                         wxAnyValueBuffer& buf)
    {
        // Use placement new
        void* const place = buf.m_buffer;
        ::new(place) T(value);  ***//Error here***
    }

    static const T& GetValue(const wxAnyValueBuffer& buf)
    {
        // Use a union to avoid undefined behaviour (and gcc -Wstrict-alias
        // warnings about it) which would occur if we just casted a wxByte
        // pointer to a T one.
        union
        {
            const T* ptr;
            const wxByte *buf;
        } u;
        u.buf = buf.m_buffer;

        return *u.ptr;
    }
};
```

I've searched for several hours but cant see anything relate to this, please help me.

More info : I'm adding wxWidgets by using NuGet, and link by static library.[image]
This is full error message.

I didn't edit anything in wxWidgets since it has been downloaded, and i'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

Comment: GCC follows up that error message with a list of the available overloads, and details of the parameter mismatch. Doesn't MSVC do that as well?

Comment: Have you changed any compilation options in `wx/msw/setup.h`? This error definitely doesn't appear when using the default options with MSVS. Also, please give the full error message and let us know about the version of MSVS you use.